# wait for iframe to load with cypress

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, cypress

I'm testing an application that uses iframes, I wanted to know if with cypress it is possible to wait for an iframe to load, because I need to ensure that the iframe has been fully loaded to perform the test.

I tried using a cy.wait(), it even worked, however, setting a time on it makes my test very slow, since there are several use cases in this iframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package [cypress-iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe) has some built-in routines to wait for the iframe to load.

From the source, it waits for the URL, ready state and load event:

```js
const hasNavigated = fullOpts.url
  ? () => typeof fullOpts.url === 'string'
            ? contentWindow.location.toString().includes(fullOpts.url)
            : fullOpts.url?.test(contentWindow.location.toString())
  : () => contentWindow.location.toString() !== 'about:blank'

while (!hasNavigated()) {
  await sleep(100)
}

if (contentWindow.document.readyState === 'complete') {
  return $frame
}

await new Promise(resolve => {
  Cypress.$(contentWindow).on('load', resolve)
})

return $frame
```

You can use that package directly without needing to implement your own wait strategy, but note the docs are a little out of date if you are using Cypress with version greater than 10.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I found a simpler solution, I spent a timeout on the iframe ID and then spent a timeout on the element I wanted to click inside the iframe, giving time for the iframe to load and making my test faster